# how can i change a href icon in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('link1').href = "images/favicon2.ico"; 
</script>
```

it works in Chrome, but I need it to work in Internet explorer. how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`HTMLElement.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute)

```
document.getElementById('link1').setAttribute('href', 'images/favicon2.ico');
```

Comment: What is the console telling you? You should do some debug to understand where is the problem. Maybe you execute that script before the DOM loaded?

Comment: <title>hi</title>
<link id="l1" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
in script,I have this:
 function getParameterByName(name){
 name=name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
 var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"), results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));}
if (getParameterByName("user").toLowerCase() == "true"){
             document.title="user";
             document.getElementByI(l1).href="User.ico";}
in IE:title is changed,but href didnt changed

Comment: The id of `<link>` tag is `l1` while you're changing `link1`, anyway this doesn't explain why it works on Chrome and not on IE.

Comment: realy I call it link1, but I changed it to l1 because I didn't have space to write the comment.